# Hibernate Criteria ResultTransformer - bean with List / Set inside

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, projection, hibernate-criteria

I have entity like this:

```
public class EntityClass{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<OtherEntityClass> others;
}
```

and bean class like this:

```
public class BeanClass{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Long> ids;
}
```

and i try to get result (`List<BeanClass>`) using following criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntityClass.class)
    .createAlias("others", "others", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")                   // this is OK
        .add(Projections.property("name"), "name")               // this is OK
        .add(Projections.property("others.id"), "others"))       // there is problem
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(BeanClass.class));

List<BeanClass> result = criteria.list();
```

Problem is (i think) in way how hibernate giving tuples into Tranformer. 
In class [AliasToBeanResultTransformer](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.10.Final/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html) i found method:

```
public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases);
```

Hibernate is "giving" into tuples rows / arrays like this (method is executed 4 times):

1st invocation

- 1
- sameName
- 23

2nd invocation

- 1
- sameName
- 24

3rd invocation

- 1
- sameName
- 26

4th invocation

- 1
- sameName
- 27

I would like it "give" there (in only 1 invocation):

- 1
- sameName
- [23,24,26,27]

Have someone solution for my ?

---

I was created temporary workaround, but it is really ugly. ([My Own Transformer](http://pastebin.com/Zj4ScdaV))